# How do you get past an exception with FileReader

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to get the user to input their file name. If the file name is valid it passes through. However, if the file name is invalid then its suppose to ask the user again for a file. If a purposely enter an invalid file name, the program doesn't get past the exception branch.

Here's the code:

```
public class LineNumbers {

    private static Scanner getFile() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scannedFile = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFile;
        boolean validFile = false;

        while (!validFile) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter your file name: ");
                inputFile = in.nextLine();
                scannedFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(inputFile));
                validFile = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e);
                System.out.print("Invalid File");
                in.next();
                scannedFile.next();
            }
        }
        return scannedFile;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = getFile().nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `in.next()` and `scannedFile.next()` in the `try`? What do you think that does? Why do you think so?

Comment: I took those out and it worked. I thought it was somehow clearing the "stream of data" so the user could put in new data. It worked for my last program which was continuously looping. I'll post the other program's code cause I feel like I'm not understanding it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do are getting problems when calling `in.next();` and `scannedFile.next();` in catch block. You have already expected in.readLine() if invalid user input occurred. Additionally you should understand that the `scannedFile` is reachable, that's why got the exception. So you cannot use  `scannedFile.next();` in the `catch` block also.

**Do following modifications**

```
    private static Scanner getFile() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scannedFile = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFile;
        boolean validFile = false;

        while (!validFile) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter your file name: ");
                inputFile = in.nextLine();
                scannedFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(inputFile));
                validFile = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.out.println("Invalid File");
                //no scanned file, input file could not find
                scannedFile = null;
                //file was not valid
                validFile = false;
            }
        }
        return scannedFile;
    }
```

Comment: The program works without having to add your code but just deleting mine. However I will use it because it adds more logic to it. Thank You.